# Can I build a staggered steel stud wall?

Tags: framing, studs, steel

I want to build a house with steel.  I'm interested in building like say 8' wide exterior walls, with staggered studs or double 3' studs to prevent thermal bridging; is this feasible?  Are the studs going to be secure enough only screwed to the top and bottom channel from just one side?

Comment: Typically, steel studs & channels are used for partition (non load-bearing) walls, often in commercial spaces. You can certainly build strong buildings of any size with steel *frames,* when those frames are correctly designed. This often means with engineers, load calculations, and joints that are welded or at least extensively bolted through.

Comment: I would think if you intend to make a wall like this that you simply put down two channels. One for the outer set of studs and one for the inner set. It may very well still be advisable to put short stiffener ties between the outer stud and inner studs, especially if you go for the narrower 3 inch studs. With two channels you have the option to space then apart and place full coverage foam board insulation in between.

Answer (score 1):

**Nope on all accounts**, since it seems you're talking about big store steel studs. You would need to have Structural Steel Studs & they aren't store bought & must be part of a submitted, approved & continuously inspected building design. After all that, then most definitely yes on all accounts.

Comment: I don't see anything other than you jumping to conclusions that specifies where @James intends to source his steel studs.

Comment: He's not talking about anything Structural nor Approved if his last sentence is: _"Are the studs going to be secure enough only screwed to the top and bottom channel from just one side?"_ That's nothing but store bought tin can stuff. He'll have a house, at the longest, only until the last nail goes into the roof shingles.